# Using PowerMock during Spring Context Initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, powermock

I am trying to write an integration test suite for a project that I didn't write and don't want to change the implementation of any code. Now in that code there is a class called SalesforceSubscriptionsManager which is a Spring Bean (component) that calls the constructor for SalesforceBusSubscriber.

```
@Component
public class SalesforceSubscriptionsManager {
    public SalesforceSubscriptionsManager() {
        System.out.println("creating bean");
        //implementation remove for brevity
        new SalesforceBusSubscriber(credentials, consumer);
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the instantiation of the SalesforceBusSubscriber class, so when the application context is set up and the bean is created it doesnt use the real Subscriber class. To do this I am using PowerMock. This is what my tests look like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {Application.class},
        initializers = { ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, SalesforceBusSubscriber.class }
)
@PrepareForTest({SalesforceBusSubscriber.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "javax.xml.transform.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.*"})
public class BaseTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static PreContextMockRule mock = new PreContextMockRule();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        SalesforceBusSubscriber postContext = new SalesforceBusSubscriber(
            new SalesforceBusCredentials(1L,"http://www.google.com", "user","pass","d"),
            Mockito.mock(Consumer.class)
        );
    }
}
```

The rule that I have created looks like this:

```
/**
 * Rule to allow powermock behaviour before spring context is initiated so that when the context
 * runs they are already applied.
 */
public class PreContextMockRule extends ExternalResource {
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("running rule");

        SalesforceBusSubscriber mockSubscriber = mock(SalesforceBusSubscriber.class);

        whenNew(SalesforceBusSubscriber.class)
                .withArguments(any(SalesforceBusCredentials.class), any(AbstractConsumer.class))
                .thenReturn(mockSubscriber);

        when(mockSubscriber.getErrorFlag()).thenReturn(false);
    }

    protected void after() {
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}
```

Now when I build my code and run, I see the following:

```
running rule
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot :: 

//more stuff

creating bean
```

So powermock is running before the context is started, the context is booted up and then the bean is created. However when stepping through the code the SaleforceBusSubscriber in the constructor is not a mock yet the one named "postContext" in the method named "test" is a mock...

My question is, how can I make powermock mock the instantiation of new objects in spring beans?

P.S. I know another way to do this is to isolate the creation of objects in a factory and mock that factory but I don't want to change any of the existing code whatsoever.

Comment: Isn't it easier to mock `SalesforceSubscriptionsManager` instead of trying to shoehorn powermock into the internals of that class?

Comment: @M.Deinum i wish. the class has some logic i wish to test, which is why I am not mocking the whole class. i have omitted the methods of that class so i guess that was unclear.

Comment: I think you're complicating yourself too much by trying to integrate `powermock`. As you mentioned yourself the easiest way is to replace the `new SalesforceBusSubscriber(credentials, consumer);` with a call to a Spring Managed Factory. Afterwards just add the factory as a `@SpyBean` in your TestClass and next just mock that call. e.g. `Mockito.doReturn(salesforceBusSubscriberMock)
.when(salesforceSubscriptionFactory).createSalesforceBusSubscriber(any(),any());`

Comment: If you need to test that class why make it a fullblown Spring Integration test? Just write a plain unit test for that class without Spring boot and inject/fix dependencies yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum fair point. now i think about it i am trying to test too much and should split into a integration + unit test separately.